# overlay a img tag with a div using negative margin-top on the sibling div

Tags: html, css, position, margin

I am trying to overlay a `img` with a `div` using negative `margin` on the `div`, the text inside the `div` is displayed over the image, while the `background` of the `div` is being displayed under the `img` .

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="a">
    <div class="b"><img src=""/></div>
    <div class="c">somebody</div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
.a{
  height:60px;
  background:#ccc;
}

.b img{
  height:60px;
  width:60px;
  background:red;
}

.c{
  background:blue;
  height:20px;
  margin-top:-20px;
}
```

i have observed this behavior in IE9 and chrome.

is this behavior as expected? 
if yes, what is the reason?

I could make the `div` `absolute` or `relative` to achieve what i am trying to do, but i am not able to understand this behaviour.

http://jsbin.com/gejuzuza/1/edit

Comment: Note sure if this is just a typo in your example, but your opening div isn't closed.

Comment: It is expected you just have to reset the stacking order by adding `position: relative;` to the `.c` div.

Comment: @Paulie_D but it doesnt happen, if the img tag is replaced by a div...

Comment: But you **do** have an image...of course your JSBin didn't. so try this. http://jsbin.com/riruwoyi/1/edit

Comment: @Paulie_D my jsbin has a img tag, and it is same whether or not i have a image inside it.. why is it different for a img than a div

Answer (score 2):

If you add `position: relative;` to your CSS for `.c`, it will put the `div` with the `c` class above the `div` with the `b` class

Comment: ok... i understand that... but if div with class c is below the img in stacking context, why does the text display over the image

Comment: Interesting question.
I noticed that this only occurs when there is an image. If there is no image, the background will overlap as well.