# when overlapping an img-tag it renders background / border behind and text in front of img

Tags: html, css

For a simple landing page I wanted to let some text box overlap an header image. To make it simple, I just have a structure like:

```
<header>
  <img src="path/to/img.png" />
  <h1>Awesome headline</h1>
</header>
```

All elements are set to `display:block` and the `h1` is dragged inside the image with a negative margin. I also gave the headline some padding and `background:white`.

Now the problem: The headline text is shown on top of the image but the background colour is behind it! You can see an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/cv12evLn/

My guess is, that a browser renders all sibling blocks in layers, starting with all backgrounds and borders, then rendering images (img-tags) and finally text on top of everything else.

**Is that right? And why the actual… I mean, that seems crazy unexpected to me.**

To solve the issue, I've put the headline in a wrapper and set this to `position:absolute`. See here for a live example: https://jsfiddle.net/f5sd1u6o/

Comment: You shoud use z-index...The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element. An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

Comment: i had a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164585/overlay-a-img-tag-with-a-div-using-negative-margin-top-on-the-sibling-div
i have no particular explanation though.

Comment: Images and objects are also known as "replaced" elements, since they do not have content per se, the element is essentially replaced by binary data. That´s why you have this strange behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Use `position:relative` rather than negative margin. Then the z-index works automatically.

```css
#container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}
#container img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
#container h1 {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 1em;
  margin: auto;
  padding: .5em 1em 1em;
  font-size: 3rem;
  background: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  top: -4.6rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="//placekitten.com/500/300">
  <h1>
    headline
  </h1>
</div>
```

To get the Z-index to work, you need to apply `position:relative` anyway but you can still use negative margin if that is a design requirement.

[**JSfiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/f5sd1u6o/2/) (with negative margin)

Basically, backgrounds are rendered first before anything else (as I understand it) so they always come at the bottom of the stacking order. You just need to create a new stacking context and changing the position property does that.

As it happens so does changing the `opacity` of the element so a quick fix is to set `opacity:.9999;`

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/5q5bzt2e/) (opacity 'hack')

Comment: Nice solution! Thanks a lot. I cannot mark it as correct answer though as my question is rather why it is rendered like this. The third comment contains an answer to the question partially.

Comment: Backgrounds are rendered first before anything else (as I understand it) so they always come at the bottom of the stacking order. You just need to create a new stacking context and changing the `position` property does that. There's an opacity hack too...I'll add that.